# Warning message from ggfortify::ggbiplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, warnings, ggbiplot, ggfortify

I am trying to use `ggbiplot`from `ggfortify` package. It seems its working fine but I am getting warning message as follows,

```
mdl <- pls::plsr(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, scale = T)
scrs <- data.frame(pls::scores(mdl)[])
loads <- data.frame(pls::loadings(mdl)[])

ggfortify::ggbiplot(scrs, loads, 
  label.label = rownames(scrs), asp = 1, label = T, label.size = 3,
  loadings = T, loadings.label = T, loadings.label.label = rownames(loads))

Warning messages:
1: In if (value %in% columns) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (value %in% columns) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Have I taken any wrong step or is it a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `ggbiplot` documentation, the `label.label=` parameter expects the column names from which to pull the names; it does not expect a vector of names. Same goes for `loadings.label.label=`. (ggplot and most tidyverse functions don't like rownames very much -- better to make them a proper column)

```
scrs$ID <- rownames(scrs)
loads$ID <- rownames(loads)
ggfortify::ggbiplot(scrs, loads, 
  label.label = "ID", asp = 1, label = T, label.size = 3,
  loadings = T, loadings.label = T, loadings.label.label = "ID")
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the same thing with `rowname_to_column` which add the row name as first-row of the data.frame. That is where, I got the problem.